# design rest API that returns json, pdf, csv

Tags: php, laravel, rest, refactoring

I have a stupid question about REST API. I created an API that returns a report as JSON/pdf/csv.

My controller has 3 methods something like this:

```
public function getJson($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the json
    // return the json
}

public function getPdf($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the pdf
    // return the pdf
}

public function getCsv($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the csv
    // return the csv
}
```

someone I work with asked me to refactor my code to be something like this

```
public function getJson($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the json
    // return the json
}

public function getDocument($startDate, $endDate, $documentType) {
    // validating inputs
    if ($documentType === 'pdf') {
        // call service pdf
    }else if ($documentType === 'csv') {
        // call service csv
    }
    // return pdf / csv
}
```

which approach is better and why?

Comment: This seems purely a style related change. The only advantage the suggestion brings is perhaps you could lower the amount of endpoints on the API. Doing this means it's less for those consuming your API to digest. 
You could do a number of things here, 1) just change it, it's no big deal. 2) Clap back by saying that the if statements could be better expressed through a switch statement. 3) keep your existing functions and just create a main function to pass on the data to the relevant file type function.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there should be one function in the controller. It is more readable in this way as a controller should contain the functions related to CRUD only and all the deep logic should be handled in services.

Move the following functions to the service in this way they can be reused by some other API that needs the same kind of docs. You can refactor these three functions to two functions but I think they are best in this way as each function here has its own unique task and is easy to reuse and read in this way.

```
public function getJson($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the json
    // return the json
}

public function getPdf($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the pdf
    // return the pdf
}

public function getCsv($startDate, $endDate) {
    // validating inputs
    // call a service to get the csv
    // return the csv
}
```

Also try to follow the PSR-2 Guide https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ for coding style guide.

Comment: _..There should be one function in the controller...._ **Why** ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ It is more readable in this way as a controller should contain the functions related to CRUD only and all the deep logic should be handled in services.